# Why it doesn't replace correctly if I run multiple replace checks?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, replace

I am replacing smile character like `:)` to images. If I use only

```
var yorum4 = "hello :)";
yorum4 = yorum4.replace(/(:\))/g, "<img class='smileys' src='smile.png' \/>");
```

It replaces correctly. However, when I use this for multiple replaces,

```
yorum4 = yorum4.replace(/(:\))/g, "<img class='smileys' src='smile.png' \/>");
yorum4 = yorum4.replace(/(:\()/g, "<img class='smileys' src='smile1.png' \/>");
yorum4 = yorum4.replace(/(;\))/g, "<img class='smileys' src='smile2.png' \/>");
```

It corrupts and output like

```
<img src="http<img class="
```

What is the correct way to replace multiple smiles ?

**Edit:** here is the full list

```
yorum4 = yorum4.replace(/(:\))/g, "<img class='smileys' src='i.png' \/>");
yorum4 = yorum4.replace(/(;\))/g, "<img class='smileys' src='j.png' \/>");
yorum4 = yorum4.replace(/(:\p)/g, "<img class='smileys' src='b.png' \/>");
yorum4 = yorum4.replace(/(:\P)/g, "<img class='smileys' src='b.png' \/>");
yorum4 = yorum4.replace(/(:\D)/g, "<img class='smileys' src='c.png' \/>");
yorum4 = yorum4.replace(/(:\d)/g, "<img class='smileys' src='c.png' \/>");
yorum4 = yorum4.replace(/(:'\()/g, "<img class='smileys' src='d.png' \/>");
yorum4 = yorum4.replace(/(:\*)/g, "<img class='smileys' src='a.png' \/>");
yorum4 = yorum4.replace(/(<\3)/g, "<img class='smileys' src='f.png' \/>");
yorum4 = yorum4.replace(/(:\o)/g, "<img class='smileys' src='he.png' \/>");
yorum4 = yorum4.replace(/(:\O)/g, "<img class='smileys' src='e.png' \/>");
yorum4 = yorum4.replace(/(:\()/g, "<img class='smileys' src='s.png' \/>");
```

Comment: Separately: Rather than making multiple passes, you might consider using the ability of `replace` to call a callback function. Like this: https://jsfiddle.net/mtvpptz8/1/

Comment: You have an unescaped semicolon in the third replace, that probably breaks the script.

Comment: Is working correctly man

Comment: If `:/` is one of your defined emoticons, you need to be careful not to include `http://` in your match. Consider using `(?=\s|$)` as a possible solution, to help ensure emoticons are meant to be emoticons (in this case, by ensuring there is space, or the end of the text after it)

Comment: @dez couldnt find it, could you please give a detail ?

Comment: @Dez: What do you mean by an "unescaped semicolon"? `;` isn't special in regular expression literals.

Comment: Its working fine, check this fiddle : [https://jsfiddle.net/tejashsoni111/7x2d13gq/](https://jsfiddle.net/tejashsoni111/7x2d13gq/)

Comment: For those who want to see the full list, I have updated the question adding full list

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thought that could be the reason of the script breaking. I wasn't sure if without quotes, semicolon might be escaped in Javascript.

Comment: @canertaşdemir: Again. Please put a **runnable** [mcve] in the question using Stack Snippets.

Comment: It is clear the `:\D` matches the protocol in an URL. You need to use something like `/:(?!\/\/)\D/`, or something more sophisticated. Or maybe you just wanted to use `/:D/`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: I don't see that in the list of things the OP is searching for, though. But something along those lines (perhaps what's getting snagged has an invalid `href`) is clearly what's happening, yes.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Look at *:\D*

Comment: I dont have smiley for :/

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Again: I don't see `:/` in the list of things the OP is replacing, which the OP claims is a full list.

Comment: I have updated my comments. Looks like `/:\D/` was intended to be `/:D/`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: The `\D` thing is spot-on, nice one. That's an answer.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. Can you add the correct one in answer side ?

Comment: @canertaşdemir: The lesson here is don't escape things that don't need escaping. `:D` is fine as is. Only escape things that need escaping, like `(`, or `)` inside a capture group. (Also note you don't need a capture group for this.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `/:\D/` pattern matches a colon and any **non-digit** symbol and can thus match a `:/` inside a protocol part of an URL.

If you meant a `:D` smiley, just use `/:D/`. Same goes for all the *literal* letters and digits: do not escape them. Also, there is no point using capturing groups around whole patterns, if you need to reference the match values in the replacement pattern, just use `$&` (not `$1`).

```js
var yorum4 = "hello :)";
yorum4 = yorum4.replace(/:\)/g, "<img class='smileys' src='i.png' \/>");
yorum4 = yorum4.replace(/;\)/g, "<img class='smileys' src='j.png' \/>");
yorum4 = yorum4.replace(/:p/g, "<img class='smileys' src='b.png' \/>");
yorum4 = yorum4.replace(/:P/g, "<img class='smileys' src='b.png' \/>");
yorum4 = yorum4.replace(/:D/g, "<img class='smileys' src='c.png' \/>");
yorum4 = yorum4.replace(/:d/g, "<img class='smileys' src='c.png' \/>");
yorum4 = yorum4.replace(/:'\(/g, "<img class='smileys' src='d.png' \/>");
yorum4 = yorum4.replace(/:\*/g, "<img class='smileys' src='a.png' \/>");
yorum4 = yorum4.replace(/<3/g, "<img class='smileys' src='f.png' \/>");
yorum4 = yorum4.replace(/:o/g, "<img class='smileys' src='he.png' \/>");
yorum4 = yorum4.replace(/:O/g, "<img class='smileys' src='e.png' \/>");
yorum4 = yorum4.replace(/:\(/g, "<img class='smileys' src='s.png' \/>");
console.log(yorum4);
```

Another hint: you might want to use word boundaries and non-word boundaries, like `/\B:\)\B/` or `/\B:D\b/` (adding non-word boundary `\B` before/after non-word chars and word boundaries `\b` before/after word chars) to match these smileys as "whole words", but it is difficult to say without the actual data.

Answer (score 4):

Just a spin of Wiktor's answer (which is the one you should accept, not this one) that incorporates the technique I mentioned in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40177904/jquery-why-it-doesnt-replace-correctly-if-i-run-multiple-replace-checks/40178213#comment67623082_40177904) and originally demonstrated in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mtvpptz8/1/):

```js
var yorum4 = "hello :)";
var smiles = {
    ":)":   "i.png",
    ";)":   "j.png",
    ":p":   "b.png",
    ":P":   "b.png",
    ":D":   "c.png",
    ":d":   "c.png",
    ":'\(": "d.png",
    ":*":   "a.png",
    "<3":   "f.png",
    ":o":   "he.png",
    ":O":   "e.png",
    ":(":   "s.png"
};
yorum4 = yorum4.replace(/:\)|;\)|:p|:P|:D|:d|:'\(|:\*|<3|:o|:O|:\(/g, function(m) {
    return "<img class='smileys' src='" + smiles[m] + "' \/>";
});
console.log(yorum4);
```

Of course, that version makes you list each smiley token twice. You could build the regex from the keys of the `smiles` object, being sure to handle any necessary escaping. I leave it as an exercise to the reader...

Comment: I'll upvote this since it is a more complete version of what I was going for :)